# How to invoke a restlet resource

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a restlet resource which looks like this:

```
@Get("json")

public List<String> retrieve() {

MyCityService nh = (MyCityService)getContext().getAttributes().get(MyCityService.class.getCanonicalName());

return nh.getReport();

}
```

as you can see it returns a List of Strings. And I try to get the returned value in a remote class using the following code:

```
ClientResource client = new ClientResource("http://remoteserver.com/mycity/nh/json");
System.out.println(client.get().getText());
```

The `getText()` method returns the whole content of the List as one string but I want to get each of the string values added in the List separately. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to go for JSON Data Exchange.
With minimal changes you can do it using any JSON Parser for Java library.
I would recommend [JSON Lib] (http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib)

In your rest web service you can use

```
@Get("json")
@Produces("MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON") // It will return JSON Object as response
public List<String> retrieve() {

MyCityService nh = (MyCityService)getContext().getAttributes().get(MyCityService.class.getCanonicalName());

return nh.getReport();

}
```

And in Client part you can use JSON.parser to parse back data and into list.

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(client.get().getText());
   System.out.println(jsonObject.get("firstname"));
   System.out.println(jsonObject.get("firstname"));
```